# How to get all place categories in facebook graph APi?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get all place categories in facebook:

1. Get access token:

   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=214063958605***&client_secret=9018d4b8240d1ebcbc1908f3fb2*****&grant_type=client_credentials

response:

```
access_token=214063958605***|J48jZWoeURB8JwhxWZlqH6*****
```

2. Get categories:

   https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=placetopic&topic_filter=all&access_token=214063958605***|J48jZWoeURB8JwhxWZlqH6*****

response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 102,
      "fbtrace_id": "DtKVcUcfdl4"
   }
}
```

Very strange, because this works fine:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&q=test&access_token=214063958605***|J48jZWoeURB8JwhxWZlqH6*****

Trying to use 3rd-party service:

https://apigee.com/console/facebook

... passing facebook authentification, making query and it works perfect!  This is the raw query:

> /search?access_token=CAAKMrAl97iIBAGVPUb9ZAzsvoDy2e1JuP69UGrc3XA8oToNAghxIqtSZBqQXfIsrepnZAXPUQZCefEafeWQdz5SDSKiBEtOJXN0nCMbRwqatyoTERZA34ZBZBwrYMFM8A5K9yw9sUBZA6ZCpZAlVIAM9FRTENJnggyLHaypagtgmMd7rqy3pTHFWEFbZCA5XQZCqqbXyAbZAuxxEiQYn6zIjwip7yxynUsDX06vvMvyu**********&type=placetopic&topic_filter=all

This access token format differs from mine. How can I get it? Why don't usual access token work with placetopic query?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the differences of so-called User Access Tokens and App Access Tokens. The latter "impersonate" an App, the other an actual User.

The Graph API defines different conditions for accessing their endpoints. This is well-documented:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search

> All Graph API search queries require an access token included in the request. The type of access token you need depends on the type of search you're executing.
>
> Searches across Page and Place objects requires an app access token.
> All other endpoints require a user access token.

Also see:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens